# JSF portlet generating different Id for different environment

Tags: jsf, primefaces, liferay-6

I am creating a dynamic form which hides/unhides fields based on selection of radio buttons.
I was using normal javascript function as given below which is working fine in my portal environment(the ids are the JSF ids which i get by viewing source).

```
 function printHiddenValue(){
         alert("hello");
       alert(document.getElementById('A1938:j_idt4:create-ticket:hiddenId').value); 
       if(document.getElementById('A1938:j_idt4:create-ticket:j_idt19:0').checked){
           alert("incident sellected")
       } else
           {
           alert("change sellected")

           }

    }
```

but fails when i deploy the war in different environment as differnrt ids are generated by the portal environment.

Answer (score 1):

You should not rely on dynamic ids, not just `A1938` part of id but also `j_idt4` may change if you change structure of your page for example. You should assign id to component `j_idt4`, and for first part you can use EL `#{facesContext.externalContext.response.namespace}` to get namespace of your portlet:

```
document.getElementById('#{facesContext.externalContext.response.namespace}:j_idt4:create-ticket:hiddenId')
```

Comment: Yes but how do I assign id to component j_idt4 as you can see in A1938:j_idt4:create-ticket:j_idt19:0 new j_idt19:0 is generated but in source i am not getting what the component is.

Comment: Well it is some naming container component I can't know as I don't have facelet code. At least try to get portlet namespace dynamically and not to rely on constant.